# How to receive inputs from UI to jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I want my jenkins job to take inputs from the UI and pass them as parameters while building . parameters can be url or files or both. Is this possible in jenkins? If yes, can someone help me how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can define parameters by selecting "This build is parameterized" in your job configuration. There are several parameter types built-in and several plugins will provide additional types.

See https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build.